# Hibernate Hql table is not mapped if page index = 0 spring boot pageable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

so i have an api build with spring boot to get all my table data with pageable

this is my get method in my controller

```
@GetMapping("")
    public Iterable<PositionDto> getPosition(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
                                            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "10") Integer size){
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
        return repository.findAllMapping(pageable);
    }
```

PositionDto.java

```
@Data
public class PositionDto implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2895197668336416172L;
    private Long positionId;
    private String title;
    private String level;
    private String parentPositionTitle;
    
    public PositionDto(Long positionId, String title, String level, String parentPositionTitle) {
        this.positionId = positionId;
        this.title = title;
        this.level = level;
        this.parentPositionTitle = parentPositionTitle;
    }
}
```

Position.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "find_all_position",
        query = "SELECT "
                    + "child.position_id as positionId, "
                    + "child.title as title, "
                    + "child.level as level, "
                    + "parent.title as parentPositionTitle "
                    + "FROM position child "
                    + "JOIN position parent "
                    + "ON child.parent_position_id = parent.position_id",
        resultSetMapping = "position_dto"
    )
    @SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "position_dto",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = PositionDto.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "positionId", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "title", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "level", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "parentPositionTitle", type = String.class),
            }
        )
    )
public class Position extends BaseAudit{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long positionId;
    private String title;
    private String level;
    private Long parentPositionId;
    
}
```

and my PositionRepository

```
public interface PositionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Position, Long> {

    @Query(name = "find_all_position", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<PositionDto> findAllMapping(Pageable pageable);
    
    Optional<Position> findById(Long positionId);
    
    List<Position> findByLevel(String level);

    Position save(Position position);
    
    void deleteById(Long positionId);   
}
```

this code is works if the page 1
[page 1 json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRz3i.png)

but in page 0 it shows error caled hibernate hql, table is not mapped....
[page 0 json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGxup.png)

what should i do ?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the problem is coming from @SqlResultSetMapping

But I have resolve this problem as

Repository return **Position** alternative **PositionDTO**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT child.position_id as positionId, child.title as title, "  +
        " child.level as level, parent.title as parentPositionTitle FROM position child JOIN position parent ON child.parent_position_id = parent.position_id", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Position> findAllMapping(Pageable pageable);
```

After on **Controller**

```
Page<Position> pagePosition = repository.findAllMapping(pageable);
    // map Position -> PositionDTO
```